# setTimeout function not working with location.href

Tags: javascript, php

i wonder why this code is not re-directing , when i use setTimeout function with location.href:

```
<?php
if( $s == 1 ){
    echo '<div class="success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i><h3>Thank You!</h3>
    Your enquiry has been sent successfully.
    <br/>
    We will get back to you soon!</div>';
}
else{
    echo '<div>Your message sending failed!</div>';
}

echo "<script>setTimeout(location.href = '123.php', 2500);</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Reading [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) always helps.

Comment: DW not showing any syntax ERROR

Comment: Yep, since it's a type error ...

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout`'s first argument needs to be a a function, so you'll need to put your command inside a function. Even something like this `function(){ location.href = '123.php'; }` will do:

```
<?php
if( $s == 1 ){
    echo '<div class="success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i><h3>Thank You!</h3>
    Your enquiry has been sent successfully.
    <br/>
    We will get back to you soon!</div>';
}
else{
    echo '<div>Your message sending failed!</div>';
}

echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '123.php'; }, 2500);</script>";
?>
```

Comment: echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '123.php'; }, 2500);</script>";

Comment: does the code appear in the source code of the page? the only other thing I could think about is that maybe using `window.location.href` might make a difference